# cygwin windows: undefined reference to gsl_vector_set after running make

Tags: c, cygwin

I'm a newbie of C language.  I'm trying to use this source code http://scholar.harvard.edu/files/jwhitehill/files/optimallabelingrelease1.0.3.tar.gz with windows 7 64-bits but I have problem to install this program.

According to the installation instruction as follows:

```
1. Install GSL, if not already installed.
2. Modify Makefile to point to the locations of the GSL and (contained within
it) CBLAS libraries and header files. If you do not have Matlab installed or do
not want to compile the Mex interface, then comment out the corresponding line.
3. Run make.
4. You may have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to 
the GSL and CBLAS libraries.
5. Run the demo (matlab_demo.m).
```

I have completed step 1 and 2 with the latest gsl version (2.2.1) but I got errors after run make in step 3 as follows:

```
/tmp/ccxc3eza.o:data.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `gsl_vector_set'
/tmp/ccxc3eza.o:data.c:(.text+0x37): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `gsl_vector_set'
/tmp/ccxc3eza.o:data.c:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `gsl_vector_set'
/tmp/ccxc3eza.o:data.c:(.text+0x6c): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `gsl_vector_set'
/tmp/ccxc3eza.o:data.c:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `gsl_vector_get'
/tmp/ccxc3eza.o:data.c:(.text+0xb6): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `gsl_vector_get'
/tmp/ccxc3eza.o:data.c:(.text+0xea): undefined reference to `gsl_vector_get'
/tmp/ccxc3eza.o:data.c:(.text+0xea): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `gsl_vector_get'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0x529): undefined reference to `gsl_vector_set'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0x529): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `gsl_vector_set'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0x56d): undefined reference to `gsl_vector_set'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0x56d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `gsl_vector_set'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0x78d): undefined reference to `gsl_sf_erf_Z'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0x78d): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `gsl_sf_erf_Z'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0x7c7): undefined reference to `gsl_sf_erf_Z'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0x7c7): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `gsl_sf_erf_Z'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0xa87): undefined reference to `gsl_sf_erf_Z'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0xa87): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `gsl_sf_erf_Z'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0xabb): undefined reference to `gsl_sf_erf_Z'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0xabb): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `gsl_sf_erf_Z'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0xef0): undefined reference to `gsl_vector_alloc'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0xef0): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0xf3e): undefined reference to `gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_alloc'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0xf66): undefined reference to `gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_set'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0xfa5): undefined reference to `gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_iterate'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0xfb6): undefined reference to `gsl_multimin_test_gradient'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0xfda): undefined reference to `gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_free'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.text+0xfe2): undefined reference to `gsl_vector_free'
/tmp/ccyjKrBy.o:prob_functions.c:(.rdata$.refptr.gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_conjugate_pr[.refptr.gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_conjugate_pr]+0x0): undefined reference to `gsl_multimin_fdfminimizer_conjugate_pr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:21: em] Error 1
```

I could not figure out what went wrong and how to fix it.  May I have your suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please report also the last commands before the error. In general `I have completed` don't tell us how you did it.